# log4net's LogManager.GetLogger() throws NullReferenceException when used in custom TraceListener

Tags: c#, log4net, tracelistener

I am attempting to transition a large application from using the `Trace` class to output notifications through `log4net`.  As such, I wrote a custom `TraceListener` to redirect output into the log4net's messaging (inspired by [this post](http://blog.catenalogic.com/post/2010/06/18/Log4net-TraceListener.aspx)).

```
public class Log4netTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Log4netTraceListener"); // Line 19

    public Log4netTraceListener() { /* nothing special */ }

    public override void TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source, TraceEventType eventType, int id, string message)
    {
        // some switching based on the TraceLevel, but eventually something like:
        logger.Error(message);
    }
}
```

The console application solution was three projects:

1. RunShipOrder - the console project that is the entry point for the application
2. ShipOrderAPI - a class library project that contains all of the code relevant to this process
3. CodeLibrary - a class library project that contains code common across many projects.

   - Log4netTraceListener is in this project

Inside of the `RunShipOrder` project, I can call `LogManager.GetLogger("Log4netTraceListener")`, and it works as expected.  However, if I try to call a method on `Trace` it throws an exception.  I have traced it back to the initial call to `LogManager.GetLogger("Log4netTraceListener")` inside of the `Log4netTraceListener` class.

The Exception thrown is a `ConfigurationErrorsException`, with an inner exception of `TypeInitializationException`, with an inner exception of `NullReferenceException`.
    The stack trace on the innermost exception is:

```
   at log4net.Core.LoggerManager.GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, String name)
   at log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, String name)
   at log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(String name)
   at CodeLibrary.Diagnostics.Log4netTraceListener..cctor() in Log4netTraceListener.cs:line 19
```

Any ideas on what might be throwing this exception from within the log4net codebase?

Comment: Have you configured log4net to tell it where to look for its config file? It's an assembly attribute.

Comment: `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = false)]` is in the `RunShipOrder` launcher.  The configuration seems like it should be fine because I can call `GetLogger(string)` from within the launcher.  I've tried adding the configuration assembly attribute to the `CodeLibrary`, but it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 2):

@drovani - excellent description.  I was seeing the same symptoms.  The issue in my case was that the System.Diagnostics.Trace output in app.config was configured to be a custom System.Diagnostics.TraceListener implementation that forwarded tracing to log4net, while at the same time enabling log4net's Internal Debugging via log4net.Internal.Debug = True in the app.config (or in code via log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = true).

What is likely happening is you are calling LoggerManager.GetLogger() in your custom System.Diagnostics.TraceListener implementation during static initialization or just prior to logging, which then creates static initialization ordering issues.  log4net is attempting to log something when it is doing its initialization but before LoggerManager is initialized.  Therefore LoggerManager.GetLogger() throws the null reference exception.

In your custom TraceListener you can somewhat guard against this by using a static property to initialize the ILogger on first use instead of in a field, but you need to be careful here. The best thing to do is not log, or log using another mechanism if log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging is true.  This would be the preferred solution.

Take a look at the source for log4net.Util.LogLog class.  This logs to Trace by default, and you'll end up deadlocked if anything gets logged by this - such as an appender error.  In your implementation of TraceListener, I'd make sure to set log4net.Util.LogLog.EmitInternalMessages = false in the constructor of your implementation, and perhaps handle the LogLog.LogReceived event and log those messages in another way.  The sad part about this is that some appender errors will not be logged due to this setting.  The log4net source is your friend here.

If you want to be really tricky, at a huge impact to performance, you'd need to check the setting of log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging before both logging a message and creating a logger.  If enabled, you can get a stack trace and walk it to make sure that log4net is not in the stack prior to calling into log4net.  If log4net is in the stack trace, you can pinvoke OutputDebugString() or use some other logging mechanism to trace the log4net internal log output.  You absolutely do not want to redirect internal log4net debug messages to log4net else risk an exception that is named similarly to this excellent site.